# Using IntelliJ like IntelliJ

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I am a backend developer working on a cocktail of JVM based languages(mostly Java). I have been using Eclipse IDE for nearly 4years until a week ago I was mandated to use IntelliJ. I had a look at IntelliJ documentation to figure out the advantages it offers for me over Eclipse,Netbeans,STS etc but it was information overload. Currently I have changed the keymap to Eclipse. I believe IntelliJ has lot more potential which is waiting to be unearthed. What specific advantages does it offer w.r.t exposing/testing REST API, connecting to NoSQL DBs,refactoring code etc over Eclipse.

Comment: You'll do yourself a favour by switching the keymap to IntelliJ default and google "intellij cheat sheet" - learn the key mappings, they are handy to know as many as possible!

Comment: +1 my coworker used Eclipse mapping and it was nightmare, also feel free to redefine any shortcut you want.

Comment: Ok, I will. :) But that still does not answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't be able to produce a detailed comparison matrix between IntelliJ and Eclipse but, for me, here are the most common things I miss when using eclipse on the workstation of some colleagues:

1. code navigation only with the keyboard
2. refactorings and their associated shortcuts (unlike Alt+Shift+L, Ctrl+Alt+V is actually "smart")
3. efficient "Find usages" (Ctrl+Alt+F7 or Alt+F7)
4. While debugging, real code edition with autocompletion (watched, code expressions, code fragments)
5. The new debugging visualization right in the editor (introduced by IntelliJ 14)

So are only the few things I use when helping colleagues. I'm not even talking about smart autocompletion, property files,

I admit that since I switched over to IntelliJ (~5 years ago) I never dove again into Eclipse. I'm sure they've improved a lot since but, from what I see on a daily basis with some coworkers, I'd rather stop programming than using Eclipse =D

Give it a real and serious try. There is a small time needed to got used to it but once you learn the key mapping and most of its productivity features, I'm almost certain you won't regret it. So far, I know nobody who has.